# How to add "where" clause in relationship eloquent way?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables :

- User
- Transaction Header
- Transaction Detail

And the relation of the table are :

- user has one transactionHeader
- transactionHeader belong to user
- transactionHeader has many to transactionDetail
- transactionDetail belong to user

And now i need to access by this way :

```
$response = User::select(['user_id'])->first();
$response->transactionHeader->transactionDetail->where('trans_detail_id', '=', '1');
```

The code above show the correct data **BUT** cannot filtered by `->where('trans_detail_id', '=', '1');`. `trans_detail_id` is inside **transactionDetail** table. NO error but my problem is why the data not filtered by `trans_detail_id='1'` ?

Please fix my code and explain why?

Thank you

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.1

Comment: @SagarGautam Avoid [forcing tags in title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried eager loading the relations with a query on the nested relation?

```
$response = User::select(['user_id'])->with(['transactionHeader.transactionDetail' => function($query) {
        $query->where('trans_detail_id', 1);
}])->first();
```

Comment: I already try that but i get another problem. How to get trans_detail_id ?

I use : $response->transaction_header //result null

Comment: `$response->transactionHeader->transactionDetail->first()->trans_detail_id`, and avoid using generic variable names. In this case it would be much more descriptive if you used `$user` instead of `$response`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way :

```
$response = User::select(['user_id'])->first();
$response->transactionHeader()->transactionDetail()->where('trans_detail_id', '=', '1');
```

and this way will also work :

```
$response = User::select(['user_id'])->with(['transactionHeader.transactionDetail' => function($query) {
        $query->where('trans_detail_id', 1);
}])->first();
```

but now you want to use a variable data instead of 1 for 'trans_detail_id'

```
$value = $request->value_to_filter_data;

$response = User::select(['user_id'])->with(['transactionHeader.transactionDetail' => function($query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('trans_detail_id',$value);
    }])->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps !

```
$response->transactionHeader->transactionDetail->where('trans_detail_id', '1');
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as what you have in your question.